# Will memory be allocated for a typedef structure pointer?

Tags: c, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following program, where i have a structure. I am going to assign some values to it and write it to a file.
But the confusion here is, i have just declared a pointer to the structure and has not allocated memory. Then how does the variable assignment works?
I am able to retrieve the values correctly from the file "/home/info"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FILEE "/home/info"

typedef struct my_info
{
   int i;
   int j;
   int k;
   int l;
}_my_info;

void main()
{
    _my_info *my_info;
    int fd;
    FILE *fp;
    my_info->i=100;
    my_info->j=300;
    my_info->k=200;
    my_info->l=400;
    fp = fopen(FILEE,"w");
    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("Error in opening file\n");
    fd=fwrite(my_info, sizeof(_my_info), 1, fp);
    if (fd<0)
        printf("Error while writing\n");
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: If you write to `*my_info` without allocating something first, it's undefined behaviour.  Why do you need a pointer anyway?  Why not just use the stack and declare `_my_info my_info`?

Comment: It doesn't work. It just seems to look like it is working. It may break later.

Comment: 3 notes; 1 - the *struct namespace* and *global namespace* are separate, so you can do `typedef struct my_info {...} my_info;` without conflict, and 2, you can also simply declare a typedef to the struct alone `typedef struct {...} my_info;` and 3, you could simply declare a static instance in your code (e.g. `_my_info my_info;` and space will be reserved, you must then use the *dot* operator (e.g. `my_info.i = 100;`, etc.)

Comment: Please discard whatever book or tutorial told you to use `void main()`. It's `int main(void)`. You check whether `fopen` succeeded, but if it fails you print an error message and then continue to access the file.

Comment: The behavior of undefined behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare `my_info`

```
_my_info *my_info;
```

it will have an *undefined* value. In your case, the value of `my_info` is within the range of valid memory addresses for RAM. So a write to it, and a read from it will take place.

However, you don't know which other memory you are changing due to this. This may cause memory corruption, especially in larger programs.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `my_info` pointer lives on the stack, it's likely the same position was used before and points at some allocated memory. You're overwriting some other data, which may or may not cause your program to crash.

In short - it works by accident.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not initialize the pointer variable, its value is random, means the pointer pointed to some random address.
When accessing the address, depending on your OS, it maybe crash, or just get some garbage data.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your current code. Before reaching the struct issue, you seem to be confusing the return values from `write` and `fwrite` with:

```
fd=fwrite(my_info, sizeof(_my_info), 1, fp);
if (fd<0)
    printf("Error while writing\n");
```

`fwrite` return value is type `size_t`. It can *never* be less than `0`. If you compile with *warnings-enabled* (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`) you will always receive a warning regarding the comparison always testing false.

Regarding space for your struct, why are you declaring a pointer? Unless you have some overriding reason in your example for declaring a pointer, simply declare a static instance of the struct so storage will automatically be reserved. If you do declare a pointer, you must then allocate space (e.g. `_my_info *my_info = malloc (sizeof *my_info);` or `_my_info *my_info = calloc (1, sizeof *my_info);` )

For your example, other than going through the exercise of dynamic allocation, there is no reason to declare a pointer, just declare an instance. The following is a short example of using an instance and writing/reading values from a file. (*note:* the comments regarding `int main()` -- and the change of the default filename to `/tmp/info.bin`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FILEE "/tmp/info.bin"

typedef struct {
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int l;
} _my_info;

/* main is type 'int', has arguments and returns a value */ 
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    _my_info my_info, my_info2; /* static instances */
    /* write to given filename, or FILEE (default)  */
    FILE *fp = fopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : FILEE, "wb");

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    my_info.i = 100;
    my_info.j = 300;
    my_info.k = 200;
    my_info.l = 400;

    if (fwrite (&my_info, sizeof my_info, 1, fp) < 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: write to '%s' failed\n",
                argc > 1 ? argv[1] : FILEE);
        return 1;
    }
    if (fclose(fp) == EOF) goto errclose;

    printf ("\n values written to : %s\n", argc > 1 ? argv[1] : FILEE);

    /* reopen file for reading, read values into my_info2 */
    fp = fopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : FILEE, "rb");
    if (fread (&my_info2, sizeof my_info2, 1, fp) < 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: read from '%s' failed\n",
                argc > 1 ? argv[1] : FILEE);
        return 1;
    }

    if (fclose(fp) == EOF) goto errclose;

    printf (" values read from  : %s\n\n", argc > 1 ? argv[1] : FILEE);
    printf ("  my_info2.i : %d\n  my_info2.j : %d\n"
            "  my_info2.k : %d\n  my_info2.l : %d\n\n",
            my_info2.i, my_info2.j, my_info2.k, my_info2.l);

    return 0;

  errclose:
    fprintf (stderr, "error: EOF returned on stream close.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/struct_write

 values written to : /tmp/info.bin
 values read from  : /tmp/info.bin

  my_info2.i : 100
  my_info2.j : 300
  my_info2.k : 200
  my_info2.l : 400
```

Let me know if you have further questions, and let me know if you had a compelling need to use a pointer-to-struct and I'm happy to help you further.

Comment: Thanks for your comment David.I just wanted to know how pointer-to-struct works.

Comment: Sure, hope it helped. In a nutshell, when dealing with structs, you just determine "Do I have a struct or pointer to struct?" If you have a struct, then you use the `'.'` operator to access members, with a pointer, you use the `'->'` operator. If you have a struct and take the address of the struct (e.g. `&structname`), you then have a pointer to *structname*. If you declare a struct, you get automatic memory management, with a pointer, it is up to you to allocate `:)`